# Suitescript 1.0 attendee sublist on event record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, sublist

I am attempting to add attendee line items on an event record using a user-event suitescript. However when I save the record, it is not adding the attendee from the script.

Any assistance on why this code is not working correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the actual text of your code, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mixes dynamic/client and standard record access mode.

For a user event before submit script you don't need the insert call. Just:

```
var newAt = nlapiGetLineItemCount('attendee') + 1;
nlapiSetLineItemValue('attendee', 'attendee', newAt, '95001');
```

For a user event after submit script similar but:

```
var eventRec = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
var newAt = eventRec.getLineItemCount('attendee') + 1;
eventRec.setLineItemValue('attendee', 'attendee', newAt, '95001');
//add more?
nlapiSubmitRecord(eventRec);
```

Comment: Thank you bknights! Worked perfectly!

Comment: on the same attendee sublist we have a column with a checkbox for Email, to send an email to the attendee, is there a way for me to find out what that checkboxs internal id would be? I dont see anything about email checkbox on the attendee sublist event record on the schema browser. I apologize for posting a link to the image, i am new here http://imgur.com/a/TA2ow

Comment: I believe its scriptid is `sendemail`

Comment: I am unable to get the email event invitations to send out. Is it because I am not actually creating the record in the UI but from within my script. By scripting it, is netsuite missing something it needs to push these emails out?

Comment: Are you also setting the body level 'sendemail' field? Normally when you are trying to script something in Netsuite it helps to think of simulating the GUI process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662708/send-email-checkbox-on-attendee-sublist-user-event-script

I had a secondary question going just referencing the email, no replies yet, but that has my code in it. I appreciate your help @bknights