# Send Email Checkbox on Attendee Sublist user event script

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

In NetSuite I have a custom record for keeping track of our safety meetings, from the record, I have a user-event script, BEFORE SUBMIT FUNCTION, running to create an event record. On the Event record -> attendee sublist, I am able to add the attendees, but I am unable to set the sendemail checkbox. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
    /*

   user event script
   before record submit
   creates a new event record based off this safety meeting record. 

   */

   function createSafetyMeetingEventRec(type){


  if(type=="create")
  {
  try
  {

    //get values from the safety meeting record
    var altName = nlapiGetFieldValue('altname');
    var message = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord53');
    var local = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord56');
    var date = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord51');
    var time = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord52');


    //name of the event record
    var eventTitle = 'SM-' + altName;

    //create the event record
    var eventRec = nlapiCreateRecord('calendarevent');

        //set the event record field values
        eventRec.setFieldValue('title', eventTitle);


        //script search for the Safety Committee group members in netsuite
        var entitygroupSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("entitygroup",null,
                    [
                       ["internalid","anyof","120147"]
                    ], 
                    [
                       new nlobjSearchColumn("entityid","groupMember",null), 
                       new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid","groupMember",null)
                    ]
                    );

        //get who created the event, this user is automatically on the attendee list, and cannot be added again. 
        var eventUserSet = eventRec.getLineItemValue('attendee', 'attendee', 1);


            for(var i = 0; i < entitygroupSearch.length; i++){


                    var newAt = eventRec.getLineItemCount('attendee') + 1;

                    var intIDuser = entitygroupSearch[i].getValue("internalid","groupMember",null);



                    if(intIDuser != eventUserSet){

                        eventRec.setLineItemValue('attendee', 'sendemail', newAt, 'T');
                        eventRec.setLineItemValue('attendee', 'attendee', newAt, intIDuser);


                    }else{

                    continue;

                    }

            }


    //set the resource calendar to Service Calendar, 3 is the internal id of the service calendar resource

    var newAtResource = eventRec.getLineItemCount('resource') + 1;
    eventRec.setLineItemValue('resource', 'resource', newAtResource, '3');

var eventId = nlapiSubmitRecord(eventRec, true);



}catch(err)
{
    nlapiLogExecution("error","Error Creating Event Record From Safety Record ","Details: " + err.message);
}




 }//end if


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need

```
eventRec.setFieldValue('sendemail', 'T');
```

before the submit

Comment: still to no avail :(

Comment: Are you in a live account or a sandbox or dev account? If you are in either of the latter check the employee record's communications tab to see if Netsuite thinks an email should have gone out.

Comment: I am using a sandbox account, however the emails will send if I manually create an event, just not from my script.